# Breakfast with friends

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

> One early morning, a group of friends meet in their favorite
>   café.
>
> Ash, the biggest in the group, remarked :
>
> "Must have been millions of years since we were all together, uh?""
>
> Affie, who was wearing her brand new elephant pants, nodded. Anthony kept on complaining about the weather back home.
>
> "Yeah, I am glad to be here with you, it is so cold at my place!"
>
> Eugenie, who was saddened by the loss of a friend, was looking at
>   Samuel and Namur, who where arguing about the possible future election
>   of Donald Trump.
>
> "These two are really inseparable", she said to
>   herself.
>
> Octavia, the smallest among her friends, stood and spoke :
>
> "Guys, I have a suprise for you! We're going to the opera tonight!"
>
> The waiter, waiting for the orders, wondered why these customers reminded him of something. But all of a sudden, he said:
>
> "Ladies and gentlemen, may I suggest some sliced bread with butter,
>   slices of cheese and ham? We also have croissants and other pastries.
>   And for drinking, is coffee fine? We also have tea, of course, and
>   orange and apple juice for you."

Who is this group of friends, and what came to the waiter's mind? *(and yes, it is related.)*

Answer (score 45, accepted):

They are the

> Seven continents

Explanation:

> The first two or three letters of their names help to identify them:
>  **As**h, the biggest - Asia
>  **Af**fie with the elephant pants - Africa
>  **Ant**hony with the bad weather - Antarctica
>  **Eu**genie with the lost friend, Great Britain - Europe
>  **Sam**uel & **Nam**ur, who are inseparable and arguing about Trump - South & North America
>  **Oc**tavia, the smallest mentioning the Sydney opera house - Oceania
>
>  Ash's remark 'millions of years since we were all together' also [makes sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea).
>
>  Finally, a [continental breakfast](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2014/06/continental-breakfasts-called/) was what the waiter had in mind.